# Client-side validation for wrapped/multi model views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, client-side-validation, multi-model-forms

I have these 2 model classes wrapped in one model. The strongly typed view and server side validation works well enough but I can't get the client-side validation working for this wrapped model class.

Here's my client-side code:

```
Sys.Mvc.ValidatorRegistry.validators.usernameEmail = function (rule) {

    var emailProperty = rule.ValidationParameters.emailProperty;
    var message = rule.ErrorMessage;

    return function (value, context) {
        if (!value || !value.length) {
            return true;
        }

        var usernameField = context.fieldContext.elements[0];
        var emailFieldId = $('input[name = "' + emailProperty + '"]').attr('id');
        var emailField = $get(emailFieldId, usernameField.form);

        //...validation stuff...

    };
};
```

The problem is that emailProperty returns only the property name stated in its model ie. "EmailAddress" but the strongly typed view assigns the name as "Model1Name.EmailAddress" since it is called like:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model1Name.EmailAddress)%>
```

Thus it returns null when looking for the property and I get an error. So I guess my questions here would be:

1. Is there a way to get the assigned model name ("Model1Name") so I
   could append it with the property name?
2. Could I pass the assigned model name from the DataAnnotations/ModelValidationRule classes? If so, how?

Here are my model classes:

```
public class Model1
{
    public string EmailAddress{ get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Model2
{
    [UsernameEmail]
    public string Username{ get; set; }
    ...
}

public class WrappedModel
{
    public Model1 Model1Name{ get; set; }
    public Model2 Model2Name { get; set; }
}
```

Side-note: The client side validation works well for single model views.

**Edit** 
After much debugging, I found out that

```
viewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("EmailAddress");
```

in my DataAnnotationsModelValidator is returning only the parameter name "EmailAddress" and is leaving out its prefix "Model1Name" thus returning the wrong Id.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom [UsenameEmail] attribute is a piece which is responsible for emitting correct client-side validation metadata. To be more precise, there should be validator adapter registered for that. You need to make sure adapter generates *full* property name, i.e. "Model1Name.EmailAddress", then "usernameEmail" client-side function will receive correct field name and will operate as expected.

See "DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(...)" for more details.
Here is implementation sample - http://weblogs.asp.net/jacqueseloff/archive/2009/12/17/asp-net-mvc-2-rc-validating-credit-card-numbers.aspx

Comment: The example you provided operates the client side validation on a single property: the one that's decorated with the validation attribute. What the OP needs is to compare the value of the property decorated with the validation attribute with another property.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: i think iamnobody doesn't need to compare two props, there is different problem... but i realized i missed the thing in the question - i did not notice the author is aware of client validation rule classes...

Comment: @iamnobody: do you use <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Model1Name.EmailAddress)%>? if so, it should work ok...

Comment: he decorated the Username property with the attribute and tries to fetch the value of the EmailAddress property on the client. I suppose he does this in order to perform some comparisons between their values, but I might be wrong.

Comment: I am trying to compare the two values but I just found out that the problem is in retrieving the FULL id with the prefix.